# java read encrypted Objects

Tags: java, encryption, file-io

Hello I have following Problem:

I have an Class/Object Access wich is Serializable.

```
public class Access implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private URL website;
private String username;
private String password;

// + some methods

}
```

Now when writing them to a File i encrypt them using a Cipher. Looks like this:
**WRITING:**

```
ObservableList<Access> userData;
userData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
...
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key128);
File file = new File("./resources/saves" + username);
file.createNewFile();
CipherOutputStream cipherOut = new CipherOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true)), cipher);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOut);

userData.forEach((item) -> {
    try {
        out.writeObject(new SealedObject(item, cipher));
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
out.flush();
out.close();
```

**READING:**

```
ObservableList<Access> access = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key128);

CipherInputStream cipherIn = new CipherInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("./resources/saves" + username)), cipher);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(cipherIn);
SealedObject sealed;
while ((sealed = (SealedObject) in.readObject()) != null) {
    access.add((Access) sealed.getObject(cipher));
}
```

If i now Load the File it seems corrupted. I find it hard to find the mistake. I think the Problem is in the load function. Am i missing something obvious here?

Error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3D23898C
```

Thank you for your time & help! :*

Comment: What happens if you comment out the (de)ciphering stuff from your methods? Can you write and read back an unencrypted object?

Comment: I just tried it, and now i get an EOF Exception while reading. I'll probably messed the loop up? **EDIT** Yes some problem with the loop. It works fine without encryption.

Comment: @Emmanuel: Not I'd try the other way around: writing and reading back a string via cipher streams, to make sure this part works OK, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, The problem is the interaction between the cipher stream and the object stream.

When you read the file, the `ObjectInputStream` asks to the underlying stream (the cipher stream) to read a very specific header. But the cipher stream has zero knowledge of that - he reads the normal amount of bytes he is supposed to, according his own protocol, in order to make sense of the encrypted data. The result is that the ObjectInputStream gets a truncated/altered header and can't process the stream correctly.

Good news is, you don't actually need it ! The `SealedObject` will take care of encryption/decryption for you. Simply remove the cipher stream and it should work.

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
```

and to read:

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
```

Now, if you *really* want to use the cipher stream (and thus effectively encrypt/decrypt the data twice with the same key), you need first to make a "first pass" on the file to decrypt it, and then open an object stream on the new decrypted file.

Comment: Merci! Thank you very much. That solved the Problem!

Comment: De rien! bon hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to call `out.flush()` **and** `out.close()` ?

If you did, some data may not be actually be written to the disk and it'll be impossible to read it again.

Comment: i did call "close()" but did not flush it. Unfortunately this does not solve the Problem. :(  I am going to edit/update my Post

Comment: Okay, that was a blind guess :) I'm going to try your code.